# macbook air i5 4gb ram when scrolling in FireFox or Chrome or Safari I see vertical tearing

Tags: web-browsing, macos

I see screen tearing pretty often while scrolling webpages up and down, and it has been like this from day 1. But now I purchased an external monitor which is huge 23 inches compared to MAC 11, and the effect is more visible. It is driving me nuts and giving me headaches.

I wonder if you see the same. I was reading allot about this problem, and it seems to be present on macbook pros also? can someone confirm I'm not alone?

In other words I'm deciding weather to go through warranty repair, or if it makes no sense if all of theme exhibit same behavior.

It is shame to see this beautiful machine, with insane price tag to be lagging when browsing web when processor is just sitting their idle at 4-12%!

This is an example I found on wiki that more or less describes what happens when I scroll up down. Effect is not so pronounced and clears when I stop scrolling, but it is sure annoying hell out of me.

[image: screen tearing]

Firefox tearing like hell, chrome less, safari exhibits jagged scrolling but less tearing of chrome and firefox.

With synthetic benchmarks I don't see any problems with hardware. But this is not particularly revealing.

Comment: I've read reports about this already like **two years ago**. This behavior is not new. **Firefox for Mac in general is not maintained as well as the Windows version**. I don't know a fix for this and I don't expect there to be anyone soon. Just think of this: Lion has been out for a year now and Firefox is still lacking features like native fullscreen and the transparent scrollbars. OSX keychain support is also lacking - and Firefox had years to work on this. Google Chrome on the other hand has integrated all of these very fast.